# use enter in loop in c

Tags: c, loops

I want to close the loop after pressing enter in this code, and I don't know where the problem is. How can I do this?
PS: 13 is the ascii code of enter

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
   char chaine[30];
   char c;
   int a=1;
while(a=1){
        
        
    scanf("%s",chaine) ;
    printf("cet chaine :%s ,a %d character\n",chaine, strlen(chaine));
    
    printf("if you want to exsit press enter");
    scanf("%c",&c);
    if (c=13){
        a=0;
        break;
    }
}
    }
```

Comment: @JacobAnderson Please do not make edits to code changing the semantics. If unsure just don't edit code at all and comment asking OP to clarify the question (or edit themselves).

Comment: Please clarify you problem, if posible add debugging information. The most simple debugging help is to temporarily add ´printf´ in the loop to see the values of variables. Just be careful to use the correct format string.

Answer (score 1):

you should use `==` instead in the if statements.

`=` is for assignments however `==` is for equality.

```
while(a==1)
```

```
if (c==13){
 a=0;
 break;
}
```